# PhantomJs: Spawn is not opening any app

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

I installed phantomJs using npm globally. Why this code isn't working?

```html
var page  = require('webpage').create();
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

page.open('http://google.com', function(status){
  if( status == 'success' ) {
    page.render('/tmp/google-snapshot.jpg');
    spawn('/usr/bin/sensible-browser', 'file:///tmp/google-snapshot.jpg');
    phantom.exit();
  }
})
```

Im using linux mint. Typing command `/usr/bin/sensible-browser file:///example.png`  in terminal works fine but why this doesn't work through script.?

Comment: How do you run this script?

Comment: It turns out phantom.exit() was getting called before spawn() can get complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out phantom.exit() was getting called before spawn() can get complete. Below code fixed the problem.

```
var page  = require('webpage').create();
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

page.open('http://google.com', function(status){
  if( status == 'success' ) {
    page.render('/tmp/google-snapshot.jpg');
    spawn('/usr/bin/sensible-browser', 'file:///tmp/google-snapshot.jpg');
  }
  setTimeout(function(){
    phantom.exit();
  },2000);
});
```

Reference: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/pull/14220